# Rails Model: includes method on self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to optimise database queries so have been adding `Model.includes(:related_model)` where appropriate.

What is the appropriate way use this within methods inside my model? For example if I have a method in my model like:

```
def some_method
    self.child_models.each do |child_model|
      total_score += child_model.attribute
    end
end
```

How do I use `includes` in instances like this? It seems natural to do it like this but it doesn't work:

```
def some_method
    self.includes(:child_model).child_models.each do |child_model|
      total_score += child_model.attribute
    end
end
```

Most times when I produce an n+1 query it seems I'm referencing the model self but I can't seem to find any examples of this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using self in an instance method so self is the instance of your class but includes is a class method. You need to use your original sample code to use includes `Model.includes(:related_model)`. I think what you really want is:

```
def some_method
  self.child_models.sum('attribute')
end
```

I would use includes when I am building conditions in a relation not looking at the children of an instance.

Comment: Thanks @JosephL - That's a great idea for the specific example but I'm asking for the more general case where logic on child models is more complex. I guess what you're saying is that once the instance has been initialised I can't then call the class method as the instance doesn't include the children. Would the best solution be to just use includes at a controller level? This feels inelegant as I may forget to do this at a controller level when using the model method.

Comment: OK, you're right - I guess the key message is if you're trying to use this on an instance then you're doing it in the wrong place. I'm probably best to rely on the bullet gem and calling includes upon the instantiation of a model instance.